# Avoid Worksheet_Change event if user changes a certain value

Tags: vba, excel, events, worksheet-function

I would like to get some ideas how to solve my problem.
Here is situation:
I am inputing value in A2 or B2 field. In I2 field there is formula which should parse inputed value in A2:

```
=IF(LEFT([@[Value 1]];3) = "240";MID([@[Value 1]];4;9);IF(LEFT([@[Value 2]];3)="240";MID([@[Value 2]];4;9);""))
```

With VBA I copied value from I2 to C2. I done that cause i want to let user change that value, but therefore dont delete formula in field. 
Problem is, when I enter values in row under, the values which user changed in C2 will be again copied from I2 field.

My code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim LastRow1 As Integer
    Dim Row1 As Integer
    Dim LastRow2 As Integer
    Dim Row2 As Integer
    Dim LastRow3 As Integer

    Row2 = WorksheetFunction.Match(Target, Range("I:J"), 0)
    LastRow2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A" & LastRow2)) Is Nothing Then
        For Row2 = 2 To LastRow2
          Cells(Row2, 3) = Range("I" & Row2).Value
        Next Row2
    End If
End Sub
```

Example of procedure:

A2 value = 24089745312045697845
Formula in I2 parsed out this = 897453120
And copied this value to C2

User change value in C2 so lets say that he wrote MODIFIED there.

Next step:
A3 value = 24053698712664234789
Formula in I3 parsed out this = 536987126
And copied this value to C3
But in same time, value in C2 is changed back to 897453120 - I want to stay word MODIFIED there.

Comment: Is there any problem to add another If statement: If Target.Address = "Whatever" Then ... your logic?

Comment: No, there is not any problem to add anything. Can u tell me which changes u meant to do?

Comment: I'd add on the beginning of procedure:

    If Target.Address="C1" Then Exit Sub

That's all!

Comment: Tried that now but didnt help. Maybe you misunderstood me. I edited my original post and added procedure what happens. Maybe it will be more clear now where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly...

```
    For Row2 = 2 To LastRow2
        'value has been already changed, do not recalculate
        If Cells(Row2, 3) <> Range("I" & Row2) Then GoTo SkipNext
        Cells(Row2, 3) = Range("I" & Row2)
SkipNext:
    Next Row2
```

**Note:** Using below condition, you'll be able to recalculate it again, if user cleaned up **"C1"** to **"C" & Row2** range.

```
If Cells(Row2, 3) <> "" Then GoTo SkipNext
```